# Get sql data group by month and category as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help with my
mssql problem. 
I have some structure of table:

```
Category   amt    year  month  
cat1      800.00  2013  jan  
cat2       30.00  2013  jan  
cat3      120.00  2013  feb  
cat4      125.00  2013  feb
```

I want data comes (group by month) example...

```
Month    cat1     cat2     cat3     cat4  
jan     800.00    30.00     0.00     0.00  
feb       0.00     0.00   120.00   125.00
```

Comment: Can you please show the query that you have tried so far?

Comment: Are there a fixed number of categories - 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you would like to get the data in a cross tab? If that is the case you can use a pivot table.

```
select
    month
  , coalesce(cat1,0) as cat1
  , coalesce(cat2,0) as cat2
  , coalesce(cat3,0) as cat3
  , coalesce(cat4,0) as cat4
from tbl
pivot(sum(amt) for category in ([cat1], [cat2], [cat3], [cat4])) p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PIVOT](http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx) for this. Please check the query:

```
SELECT 
    [Month], 
    isnull(cat1, 0.00) cat1, 
    isnull(cat2, 0.00) cat2, 
    isnull(cat3, 0.00) cat3, 
    isnull(cat4, 0.00) cat4 
FROM(
        SELECT 'cat1' Category, 800.00 amt,2013 [year], 'jan' [month] UNION
        SELECT 'cat2' Category, 30.00 amt, 2013 [year], 'jan' [month] UNION
        SELECT 'cat3' Category, 120.00 amt, 2013 [year], 'feb' [month] UNION
        SELECT 'cat4' Category, 125.00 amt, 2013 [year], 'feb' [month]
    )UP
    PIVOT (SUM(amt) FOR Category IN (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4)) AS PVT
```